# Dynamic SQL within a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

From researching the challenge I am faced with currently, it appears I cannot use variable names to bind columns or other system objects in a SQL `SELECT` statement.

Below is the `SELECT` statement I have that is supposed to retrieve records from a table object created in a stored procedure

```
SELECT @office_acronym 
FROM @ALLCOMPONENTSFTPCUMMSTAFFTOTAL 
WHERE [PPDate] = @selected_date
```

What is the best way of constructing this query assuming `@office_acronym` is dynamic and `@ALLCOMPONENTSFTPCUMMSTAFFTOTAL` is a variable table object that runs in a stored procedure?

To clarify on my question above a bit further, the table `@ALLCOMPONENTSFTPCUMMSTAFFTOTAL` is created within a stored procedure and displays these records shown here:

[image]

The desired select statement should be able to iterate within a cursor and store each columns value based on selected date as this will be displayed in another table used for a reporting application.

Comment: You *suggest* that the name of the column is dynamic here, but that `@ALLCOMPONENTSFTPCUMMSTAFFTOTAL` is a table type variable, so that variable **must** be being built dynamically; it can't not be as otherwise it couldn't have dynamic columns. If so, it'll have no scope outside of the dynamic statement it was created it, so doing what you're trying to do above is already too late. If you try `EXEC sp_executesql N'DECLARE @T table (I int);'; SELECT * FROM @T;` you'll notice it fails.

Comment: Conversely, you can't reference a variable declared outside a dynamic statement, in a dynamic statement; again due to scope: `DECLARE @T table (I int); EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM @T;';` also fails. We need to full picture here, not a small part of it.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code is not clear.  Also, having to do this suggests an issue with your data model, so you might want a fix for that as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at my issue here. In answering your question Larnu, the column names in the table sample above are not dynamic however i want to have the SQL executed within a cursor and iterating through the columns beginning from the [ODA] column. Please let me know if my explanation is still not clear enough.